# Cannot build IdentitySaml2 projects

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to implement SSO using IdentitySaml2 to authenticate but the projects are not being built. I am using .net framework 4.7.2.

UPDATED: Though I could not build the main source solution (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2). I managed to create a sample site and install nuget package. I also added code files like IdentityConfig, Authcontroller, DefaultClaimsAuthenticationManager and views and added the settings below in webconfig. I am not sure about these settings and did not find proper documentation. Currently idpmedatadata is throwing exception due to improper url.

```
<add key="Saml2:IdPMetadata" value="https://localhost:44305/metadata"/>
<add key="Saml2:Issuer" value="urn:itfoxtec:identity:saml2:testwebapp"/>
<add key="Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination" value="https://test-adfs.itfoxtec.com/adfs/ls/"/>
<add key="Saml2:SingleLogoutDestination" value="https://test-adfs.itfoxtec.com/adfs/ls/"/>
<add key="Saml2:SignatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<add key="Saml2:SigningCertificateFile" value="~/App_Data/itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebapp_Certificate.pfx"/>
<add key="Saml2:SigningCertificatePassword" value="!QAZ2wsx"/>
<add key="Saml2:CertificateValidationMode" value="ChainTrust"/>
<add key="Saml2:RevocationMode" value="NoCheck"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please be more specific in regard to the exception?

If you are building a ASP.NET MVC .NET 4.7.2 solution you should use the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc Version 3.0.0 package. I expect it is not at .NET Core application.

You can find examples her: https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test

UPDATED:
The ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 component acting as a relying party can either be configured with or without the IdP metadata.

**Using the IdP metadata**

The IdP trust configuration only needs the metadata:

```
<add key="Saml2:IdPMetadata" value="https://localhost:44305/metadata"/>
```

The IdP metadata is loaded in `IdentityConfig.RegisterIdentity()` like this:

```
var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
{
    Saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
    Saml2Configuration.SingleLogoutDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleLogoutServices.First().Location;
    Saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
}
```

The metadata kan be loaded online `ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(...)` or from a file `ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromFile(...)` or from a string `ReadIdPSsoDescriptor(...)`

**Configure the IdP without metadata**

The IdP trust needs the IdP login and logout endpoints as well as the IdP signing certificate:

```
<add key="Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination" value="https://some-idp.test.com/login/"/>
<add key="Saml2:SingleLogoutDestination" value="https://some-idp.test.com/logout/"/>
<add key="Saml2:SignatureValidationCertificate" value="~/App_Data/IdP_signing_certificate.crt"/>
```

The IdP configuration is loaded in `IdentityConfig.RegisterIdentity()` like this:

```
Saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination"]);
Saml2Configuration.SingleLogoutDestination = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Saml2:SingleLogoutDestination"]);

Saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.Add(CertificateUtil.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Saml2:SignatureValidationCertificate"])));
```

**Relying party identifier**

The unik relying party identifier:

```
<add key="Saml2:Issuer" value="urn:itfoxtec:identity:saml2:testwebapp"/>
```

**Signing certificate**

The required signature algorithm is most likely SHA-256:

```
<add key="Saml2:SignatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
```

Instead of loading the signing certificate from a file like this:

```
<add key="Saml2:SigningCertificateFile" value="~/App_Data/itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebapp_Certificate.pfx"/>
<add key="Saml2:SigningCertificatePassword" value="!QAZ2wsx"/>
```

The certificate can be loaded by a thumbprint from the Windows Certificate Store or a TLS certificate in a Azure App Service:

```
<add key="SigningCertificateThumbprint" value="XXXXX...XXXXX"/>
```

Then the `IdentityConfig.RegisterIdentity()` needs to be changed to load the certificate by thumbprint:

```
Saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Saml2:SigningCertificateThumbprint"]);
```

**Certificate validation**

The IdP certificate chain and revocation can be validated if required.

Normally the certificate chain and revocation is not validated:

```
<add key="Saml2:CertificateValidationMode" value="None"/>
<add key="Saml2:RevocationMode" value="NoCheck"/>
```

It required to validate the certificate chain and revocation:

```
<add key="Saml2:CertificateValidationMode" value="ChainTrust"/>
<add key="Saml2:RevocationMode" value="Online"/>
```